# Queryset after login in created login panel doesn't display in html

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem. I've create a login and registration site seperated from Admin Login. When I login to panel as for example John i have a choise to add new record via forms. After that I want on dashboard display the records created exacly and only by user John. Problem is that, if I wrote in my **dashboard.html** the code

```
<h1>Strony www</h1>
{% for website in website_list %}
{{website.website}}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

the html responde me only label **Strony www** and thats all. It's not displaying me records created by the users from dashboard panel.
I have in my **view**

```
def website(request):
    website_list = Website.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-User')
    context = {'website_list:', website_list}
    return render(request, 'konto/dashboard.html', context=context)
```

If I create the records using Django Admin Panel, the records are visible in dashboard. Where is a problem in my project? I want to say in every html file I using the code on the beggining

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

EDIT:
my **models.py** is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Website(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Użytkownik")
    website = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Strona www', unique=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Strona www'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Strony www'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.website

class Keyword(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Użytkownik")
    www = models.ForeignKey(Website, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Strona www")
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Słowo kluczowe", unique=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Słowo kluczowe'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Słowa kluczowe'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword
```

Comment: Can you put the code of your Website model? I think that the problem Is your order_by. Try to make the queryset without it.

Comment: Nazkter I've update my question. Check the edit.

Comment: You're ".order_by('-User')" clause cannot work (it's "user" not "User"), and is totally useless here anyway since you're filtering on the user.

Comment: wrt/ the question itself: check your db to make sure you have any website belonging to the current user.

Comment: Bruno, how to fix it? What I must write to display records correctly?

Comment: I have added the webpages by users

Comment: @killerbees please read my comments. To answer the "how to fix it", you must first know _if_ there's actually something to fix ("check your db to make sure you have any website belonging to the current user") and if yes what. This is called debugging, and is part of the process of writing a good SO question. Also it's not something anyone can do without access your code and data - IOW only _you_ can do it. There's no obvious error in the code you posted - except for the capitalized "User" in the order_by clause but this is obviously not your real code since you'd get an exception instead.