# How to display records belongs only for user instead for all users

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem. I want to to display in list only records belongs to user whos add it. In my app when I'am login as 'user' and I want to add new records incude records from list, I see all records in db from ForeignKey. How to make it correctly?
[image]

In 'Strona www' when I expand the list I see all records, not only records added by user personally.
My **view** for it is:

```
@login_required
def new_keyword(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_keyword = KeywordForm(request.POST)
        if new_keyword.is_valid():
            new_keyword=new_keyword.save(commit=False)
            new_keyword.user = request.user
            new_keyword.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Pomyślnie dodano słowo kluczowe')
            return render(request, 'konto/new_keyword_ok.html')
    else:
        new_keyword = WebsiteForm()
    return render(request, 'konto/new_keyword.html', {'new_keyword':new_keyword})
```

in **forms.py** I have:

```
class KeywordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Keyword
        fields = ('www', 'keyword')
```

**models.py**

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Użytkownik")
    www = models.ForeignKey(Website, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Strona www")
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Słowo kluczowe", unique=False)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('new-keyword/', new_keyword, name='new_keyword'),
```

and **html** for display the form is:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ new_keyword.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Dodaj nowe słowo kluczowe" ></p>
    <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Powrót do monitoringu</a>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

EDIT:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Website(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Użytkownik")
    website = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Strona www', unique=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Strona www'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Strony www'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.website

class Keyword(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Użytkownik")
    www = models.ForeignKey(Website, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Strona www")
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Słowo kluczowe", unique=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Słowo kluczowe'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Słowa kluczowe'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword
```

Comment: You don't need the `user` foreign key in `Keyword` - you can get the user from `keyword.www.user`.  Also why is your view using a `KeywordForm` when handling a POST and a `WebsiteForm` when handling a GET ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `request.user` to your form and use the inverse relation `user.website_set` :

forms :

```
class KeywordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Keyword
        fields = ('www', 'keyword')

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):            
        super(KeywordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['www'].queryset = user.website_set.all() 
        self.user = user

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(KeywordForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.user
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

views:

```
@login_required
def new_keyword(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_keyword = KeywordForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if new_keyword.is_valid():
            new_keyword.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Pomyślnie dodano słowo kluczowe')
            # DONT DO THIS ! REDIRECT INSTEAD
            return render(request, 'konto/new_keyword_ok.html')
    else:
        new_keyword = KeywordForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'konto/new_keyword.html', {'new_keyword':new_keyword})
```

As a side note: after a successful POST [you want to redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (even if to the same url). This avoids a lot of troubles (and duplicate submissions) when a user reloads the page

Comment: Great Bruno its working thank You. Maybe You can help me with another problem? I've create a question but still I don't know how to solve it. Here is a link to my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48652385/queryset-after-login-in-created-login-panel-doesnt-display-in-html

Comment: And if I want to limit for example 1 user can add only 1 website and 5 keywords, I need to declare it in view or forms?

Comment: If those are hard rules, they should be implemented in the model (to prevent new instances creations whatever when the user has reached it's quota). Then at the emplates level you should check the quota and not display links to the "add" views, and at the "add" views level you should check the quota again and display an error message instead of a form.

Comment: Ok I will try with it when I fix the problem how I wrote You in the another question

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the user id to your form and then set a queryset for your field

like this:

**How to pass the user to your form:**

in your view:

```
@login_required
def new_keyword(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        #### Notice this part.
        new_keyword = KeywordForm(data=request.POST, u=request.user)
        if new_keyword.is_valid():
            new_keyword=new_keyword.save(commit=False)
            new_keyword.user = request.user
            new_keyword.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Pomyślnie dodano słowo kluczowe')
            return render(request, 'konto/new_keyword_ok.html')
    else:

        # Notice this part.
        new_keyword = WebsiteForm(data=None, u=request.user)
    return render(request, 'konto/new_keyword.html', {'new_keyword':new_keyword})
```

**How to retrieve the user in form and set the queryset:**

forms.py:

```
class KeywordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Keyword
        fields = ('www', 'keyword')

    def __init__(self, current_user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.u = kwargs.pop("u") ## The user you just passed.
        super(KeywordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['www'].queryset = Website.objects.filter(user=self.u) ## Setting the queryset.
```

Comment: Ok I will try it :)

Comment: name user_id is not defined :(

Comment: You didn't post your other model. I don't know if it has a user field there or not. and i'm assuming that the field you want to filter is the 'www' field. is that correct?

Comment: Sorry yes I didn't paste the second model. I want to display the websites list belongs only to exacly that user whos add this records. Check edit I'v added the full models.py

Comment: I try your code but now if I want to add new keyword responde me : __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'u'

Comment: did you add `data=request.POST, u=request.user` to your view?. and `data=None, u=request.user` to the second one?